# looping through list of dates in R

Tags: r, date, representation

Here is my example:

```
test_list <- c(as.Date('2017-03-08','2017-03-08' ))

    for(el in test_list){
      print(el)
    }
```

It generates:
17641

This is date representation. I am curious why R behaves this way.

Comment: Try: `test_list <- list(as.Date('2017-03-08'),as.Date('2017-03-08' ))`

Comment: @PierreLapointe I tried your suggestion and got back: `"2018-04-20"`

Comment: Should have been  `as.Date(c('2017-03-08','2017-03-08' ))`

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you want to get back?
One time '2017-03-08' or two times as in the code below?

```
test_list <- as.Date(c('2017-03-08','2017-03-08'))

for(el in test_list){
   print(as.Date(el, origin = "1970-01-01"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pierre Lapointe is correct that calling multiple arguments with in `as.Date` is part of your issue.

The number `17641` has to do with [how R stores dates](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-date-values/).  Calling `test_list` yields `"2018-04-20"`, which I would guess means it's added those two dates.

The origin date in R is `1970-01-01`.  If you add `17641` to that, you get `2018-04-20`.  So R is returning the integer corresponding to your date, which can be verified by calling `class(el)`, which makes sense because in a loop your are referring to elements in `test_list` by their ordinality (ordinance?)

The following worked fine for me.  I'm not exactly sure why, but if it ain't broke, don't fix it!

```
for (el in 1:length(test_list)){
  print(test_list[el])
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. Neither of those values were print representations of today's Date. The problem was with the passing of two character values to the `as.Date` function and having the second value be received by the `format`-parameter.

Comment: @42- "This is date representation.  I am curious why R behaves this way".  Seems to me like the question asking about why an integer was produced by `as.Date`.  It's not the only possible interpretation of the question, but Pierre had already covered your interpretation

Comment: Your explanation might have been part of what could be a "correct answer" if there had been two numbers and they actually bore some connection to the dates that had been given as input, but neither of those conditions were satisfied. Then you said you got the correct result with code that could not possibly have been what the OP had given as a starting point.